# Creating a translucent "dialog activity"

Tags: android

I have a dialog-style activity that appears over my main activity in an Android application. How can I get the background to be translucent? Not transparent, but translucent - say 70% opaque. I've tried applying this theme to the activity:

```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
      </style>
```

and several variations on this but still the dialog activity appears 100% opaque. Also, the layout xml of the activity itself (and elements displayed on it), specify a background of "#70000000".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For totally transparent dialog you can use this :

Step 1> Create a colors.xml file in the ‘values’ folder under ‘res’ and add the following line..

```
<drawable name="transparent">#00000000</drawable>
```

Step 2> Create a styles.xml file in the ‘values’ folder under ‘res’ and the following lines…

```
<style name="Transparent">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">
@android:style/Animation.Translucent
</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
</style>
```

(I guess the tags and attributes are self explanatory…)

Step 3> Actually, that's it……………………

Let’s add this to a dialog…..

Step 4> Create a class with the following lines……

```
public class DialogBox extends Dialog {

    public DialogBox(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_OkButton);
        setListeners();
    }
}
```

(Make sure you create a layout for the dialog)

Step 5> Next create an activity class as follows….

```
public class T_Temp extends Activity {

    private DialogBox dialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        dialog = new DialogBox(this, R.style.Transparent);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

or you can use this to make dialog attractive to add blur effect ....

Just check this out: there is near about 30% transparency...

```
 dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(WordCube.this)  
    .setTitle(WordCube.this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))  
    .setMessage(s)  
    .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)  
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_close, null)  
    .show();
```

Below shows the code needed to add blur and remove dimming of the background (as I think the blur looks nicer when the background is well lit).

```
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=0.0f;  
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```